# Is it necessary or even correct to put "in" after the verb "cause"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Recently, I encountered the sentence below.

> Implicit copy constructor copies an object bit by bit so pointer address will be copied **causing in** two different objects sharing same memory location.

I'm still scratching my head about the expression "causing in". Why do we need "in"?

Comment: We don't. It shouldn't be there. It should be either “causing two different objects to share” or “resulting in two different objects sharing”. The entire paragraph is clearly written by a non-native speaker. It contains several grammatical errors that no native speaker would ever make.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no preposition "in". Perhaps the writer was thinking of the verb "resulting", which can take the preposition "in". For example,

> *Causing vs. resulting in?*
>
> Implicit copy constructor copies an object bit by bit so pointer address will be copied **resulting in** two different objects sharing same memory location.

I actually think that the word *causing* is not ideal. Better to use words/phrases like *producing*, *creating*, or *resulting in*. These indicate creation (of a new object), whereas *causing* does not.

I should also point out that the absence of the definite article is conspicuous. I would prefer this:

> *Let's try adding articles.*
>
> The implicit copy constructor copies an object bit by bit so the pointer address will be copied, resulting in two different objects sharing the same memory location.